# Trying to archive facebook chat message history for a single contact

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to archive the chat history for one contact of mine from facebook, there are over 70,000 messages so the settings/archive option is not working very well.  So far, I have attempted to use the following code from the m.facebook.com/messages page and clicking on the specific contact.

```
setInterval(function () {
document.getElementById('see_older')
.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].click();
}, 500);
```

this seems to do the job, but I am not sure how to get this code to stop running.  I need some way to stop it, as when it gets to the start of the chat log, the page changes and an error is shown.  After having it run for a few hours, that becomes quite frustrating!

the reason why I need to do this is that throughout the past 18 months, we have exchanged important information and I need to be able to search for this...

I am new to this, so any assistance that could be given would be appreciated!  If you think I should change my code, please let me know what I should use instead.  If I can get the code to stop near to the start of the chat history, I can manually click the button the last few times to get it to the exact start, but doing this manually from the latest messages takes ages (sat here for 12 hours clicking previously and only got 1/5th the way through!

Cheers for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do right now is called "scraping", which is not allowed: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Since the `read_mailbox` permission is deprecated, there is no (legal) way to get access to the user inbox anymore.